# Unable to select an element which is already in an element in appium (python selenium)

Tags: python, appium

I am automating login page in an Android app, right next to username text box there is a country region option to choose before login.

What am trying to do:

**Trying to tap on country flag element** and then it will open a page to choose which country to login.

What I did:

In Appium by selecting the flag element, username or email address section is getting selected. and hence element id for username is getting displayed and so, I selected flag section using coordinates but what happens is works for me but the problem is on different display size android devices it cant find that element in that same coordinates.

**Code:**
`TouchAction(driver).tap(None, 651, 796, 1).perform()`

**what should I do in this case? any thoughts?**

[image]

Comment: can you share your code for the automation

Comment: You may not have id for that element, you can click the element using x,y coordinates of your main element with some math calculation so that if you run any device it will work

Comment: @Mani that is what am doing right now, but the coordinates changes for all different devices. how to solve that is the problem for me?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the Hierarchy of the elements on the page.

You are trying to tap on a position, ok but what exactly happens is that UI Automator (Or other drivers you're using) may tap on the different layout element that my not visible to you.

**Solution:**

You should find the complete hierarchy xpath then do action with it.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("*{your elements full hierarchy XPATH}*")).getText();
```

for example:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.support.v4.widget.i[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.support.v4.view.ViewPager[1]/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView[1]/android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[2]/android.widget.TextView[2]")).getText();
```

I use and suggest Katalon Studio > Spy tools (instead of UiAutomator2 tools from android SDK) for this.

Here is the screenshot of the Katalon Studio Spy tool. (the XPATH address value can be easily copied, I just hovered it to show what I'm saying.)

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is not helping, since there is no element id to that flag section

Answer (score 0):

Try below code & accordingly you need do math of x & y coordinates

```
        MobileElement element = (MobileElement) driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@name=Username or email adddress]");
        int y_coodinate = (element.getLocation().getY() + element.getLocation().getY() + element.getSize().height) / 2;
        int x_coodinate = element.getLocation().getX() + element.getSize().width - (element.getLocation().getX() + element.getLocation().getX() + element.getSize().width) / 10;
        new TouchAction(driver).longPress(PointOption.point(x_coodinate, y_coodinate)).release().perform();
```

Comment: according to your code where should I mention x and y coordinates where the flag is present? and what math do you exactly mean

Comment: also am coding in python fyi

Comment: if you want to understand, will connect through any chatting channel

Comment: sure am happy to get more info :) please let me know your convenient way